# Add image to node that is being painted onto JPanel class

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I'm making a Java game. I have a Board class which extends JPanel, and have painted a node `jim`, which is an object instance of Ball class, to the screen using the `paintComponent(Graphics g) {`. I can move the Ball object around on the JPanel using arrow keys.

Instead of representing the Ball object as a red square, I would like to have an image loaded.

Board class extends JPanel:

`jim = new Ball(0, 0, 50, 50, "jim");`

Ball class:

```
public class Ball extends Component {
    int x, y, w, h;
    BufferedImage jimImg;

    public Ball(int xLoc, int yLoc, int width, int height, String imgtype) throws IOException {
        x = xLoc;
        y = yLoc;
        w = width;
        h = height;
        jimImg = ImageIO.read(new File("resources/Jim.png"));
        loadImages(imgtype);

    }
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(jimImg, 200, 0, null);
    }
```

It's not drawing on top of the red square though, or even appearing at all.

[image]

I have also tried appending the image as a JLabel... here's code within the Ball class:

```
public void loadImages(String imgType) throws IOException {

    if (imgType == "jim") {
        JLabel utc = new JLabel("test");
        ImageIcon utcImg = new ImageIcon("resources/Miller.png");
        utc.setIcon(utcImg);
    }
}
```

But since `Ball` class is not a JPanel, I can't add the label to the object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Don't compare Strings with `==`, use `equals`

   ```
    if (imgType == "jim")   ==>>   if ("jim".eqauls(imgType))
   ```
2. You should be reading from a URL and not a File object. A URL can be obtained by using `getClass().getResource()`. e.g.

   ```
   jimImg = ImageIO.read(
               Ball.class.getResource("/resources/Jim.png"));
   ```
3. You should use a `try/catch` in the constructor, so you won't have to later when you instantiate the `Ball`
4. It's preffered to paint on `JPanel` and override its `paintCompoent`, or `JComponet`
5. You never actually use the variable taken from your constructor to use to paint`

   ```
   g.drawImage(jimImg, x, y, w, h, this);
   ```
6. When working with painting, you should override the `getPreferredSize` of the `JPanel` so the frame will size it accordingly.

---

Here's a running example that works. Keep in mind my file structure look like

```
    ProjectRoot/src/resources/image.png
```

---

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Ball extends JPanel {

    int x, y, w, h;
    BufferedImage jimImg;

    public Ball(int xLoc, int yLoc, int width, int height) {
        x = xLoc;
        y = yLoc;
        w = width;
        h = height;
        try {
            jimImg = ImageIO.read(
                    Ball.class.getResource("/resources/stackoverflow5.png"));
            System.out.println(jimImg);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(jimImg, x, y, w, h, this);
    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(400, 400);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new Ball(50, 50, 100, 100));
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

---

### EDIT

in response to OP commment

> "the way my classes are structured: Main class adds JFrame, where I add a new Board class object to the JFrame (Board class extends JPanel). Then I have Board class extends JPanel, which adds a new Ball object and has keyboard methods, etc... so I can move the Ball around. Then Ball Class is just a node with get/set methods getX(), setX() etc. So I can't add an image to the Ball class without extending JPanel?"

It doesn't look like you need ball to be a Component at all. Instead of making the ball a compoent, just make it a regular class. And in the paintComponent of your Board JPanel, just call ball.paint() for each ball you have.

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Board extends JPanel {

    Ball ball = new Ball(50, 50, 200, 200);

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        ball.drawBall(g);
    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(400, 400);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new Board());
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}

class Ball {

    int x, y, w, h;
    BufferedImage jimImg;

    public Ball(int xLoc, int yLoc, int width, int height) {
        x = xLoc;
        y = yLoc;
        w = width;
        h = height;
        try {
            jimImg = ImageIO.read(
                    Board.class.getResource("/resources/stackoverflow5.png"));
            System.out.println(jimImg);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void drawBall(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(jimImg, x, y, w, h, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: the way my classes are structured: Main class adds JFrame, where I add a new Board class object to the JFrame (Board class extends JPanel). Then I have Board class extends JPanel, which adds a new Ball object and has keyboard methods, etc... so I can move the Ball around. Then Ball Class is just a node with get/set methods `getX(), setX()` etc. So I can't add an image to the Ball class without extending JPanel?

Comment: All of these ideas can still be taken into account do what you need to acheive. This is just an example based on the code you have above.

Comment: It doesn't look like you need ball to be a Component at all. Instead of making the ball a compoent, just make it a regular class. And in the `paintComponent` of your `Board JPanel`, just call `ball.paint()` for each ball you have

Comment: See my **EDIT**. I edited it using a `Ball` class that is not a `Component` and used a `Board` class for the painting.

Comment: okay, im my Board class, I did `jim.paint(g);` (jim is name of Ball object, the red block above), in Ball class, I did `Image jimImg = ImageIO.read(new File("resources/UTC.png"));`, then `public void paint(Graphics g) { g.drawImage(jimImg, 0, 0, null);}` (the way you had it above with the `ImageIO.read` try/catch, it was throwing `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!` error)

Comment: Thanks for that. But it's still not rendering the image

Comment: Look at the file structure I used and make sure yours is like this. Also when using the `getResource` you need to make sure you use the `/` in front of the string path` . You're getting the illegalargument because the way you're calling the image is incorrect. Look at my **EDIT* code.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45561/discussion-between-growler-and-peeskillet)